# Problemas con autocompletar en SublimeText 3 y Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, autocompletar, emmet

Estoy usando SublimeText 3 en Ubuntu y no "autocompleta" correctamente. Por ejemplo, al escribir lorem150 y pulsar [TAB] debería generar un lorem de 150 palabras pero no funciona bien. Solo genera lorem cuando lo escribo sin numeros. Me pasa lo mismo siempre que quiero autocompletar algo que lleve numeros. html:5 no funciona solo funciona html. AL meter clases también me pasa. Al usar cadenas de tipo div.col-md-6 tampoco funciona solo funciona si pongo div.col-md- y luego pongo el 6 despues de pulsar [TAB]. 
Espero explicarme correctamente.
Gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas instalar el paquete `emmet` en Sublime Text. Para poder instalar paquetes necesitas instalar [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3).

Abre la consola de Sublime Text (View -> Show Console) y pega lo siguiente:

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '2915d1851351e5ee549c20394736b442' + '8bc59f460fa1548d1514676163dafc88'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

Dale a enter y espera a que se instale. Una vez hecho reinicia Sublime Text. Para instalar paquetes abre la paleta de comandos (Tools -> Command Palette... o utiliza el atajo ctrl+shift+p). Escribe `install`, selecciona la primera opción, y posteriormente escribe el paquete que quieras instalar, en este caso `emmet`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez instalado ya tendrás el autocompletado que quieres obtener. Pero ahora bien, por defecto, el autocompletado de emmet está configurado para trabajar con el atajo `ctrl+e`. Si quieres cambiarlo por `tab` solo necesitas añadir esto en tus atajos personales (Preferences -> Keybindings - User):

```
[
  {
    "keys": [
      "tab"
    ], 
    "args": {
      "action": "expand_abbreviation"
    }, 
    "command": "run_emmet_action", 
    "context": [
      {
        "key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"
      }
    ]
  }, 
]
```

Reinicia Sublime Text una vez más, y ya tienes configurado el autocompletado de `emmet` en la tecla `tab` de Sublime Text.

Saludos.

Comment: Solucionado! Emmet ya lo tenía instalado pero no sabía que en linux el atajo de teclado es Ctrl+e. En Windows es Tab por defecto... He modificado la configuración de usuario como me has indicado y ahora funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Me alegro, a mi también me has enseñado que en Windows funciona por defecto. Para dar por finalizada la pregunta, marca la respuesta como válida. Saludos.

Comment: Realice la instalación y configuración indicada, pero tuve un problema, en mi caso escribí algunos snippets pero luego de la configuración ya no me cargo con el tab los **tabTrigger** que había configurado. así que lo tuve que dejar con el ctrl+e para usar el lorem.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho